# Toolbar does not work in Linear Layout but if I put toolbarAttempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, toolbar

App will crash and i handle with try catch ..its give me this in catch. Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
.if some one know .it will very helpful for me .. toolbar is very
important for me ..I must need it ..so plz help me.

> Xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="false">



  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:id="@+id/parent_linear_layout"
      tools:context=".ServicesAndRateList">


    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

      <include
          android:id="@+id/toolbar1"
          layout="@layout/toolbar"/>
    </LinearLayout>

      <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
          android:orientation="horizontal" >
      <EditText
          android:id="@+id/service"
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_weight="2"
          android:hint="@string/edittext_service"
          android:inputType="text"/>
      <EditText
          android:id="@+id/charges"
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_weight="2"
          android:hint="@string/edittext_charge"
          android:inputType="number"/>
      <EditText
          android:id="@+id/time"
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_weight="2"
          android:hint="@string/edittext_time"
          android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
          android:cursorVisible="false"
          android:focusable="false"

          android:inputType="number"/>
      <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/Sub"
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="40dp"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:background="@android:drawable/ic_delete"
          />


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

      <Button
          android:id="@+id/add"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
          android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
          android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
          android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
          android:background="@drawable/ripple"
          android:layout_gravity="center"
          android:onClick="onAddField"
          android:textColor="#000"
          android:text="Add Field"
          android:paddingLeft="5dp"/>
      <Button
          android:id="@+id/submit"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
          android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
          android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
          android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
          android:background="@drawable/ripple"
          android:layout_gravity="center"
          android:textColor="#000"
          android:text="Register"
          android:paddingLeft="5dp"/>


    </LinearLayout>


  </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

> toolbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="#0190CA"
    android:elevation="4dp">

</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: also post your toolbar layout here

Comment: you mean picture of xml view..?

Comment: not picture , just copy and paste here

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="#0190CA"
    android:elevation="4dp">

</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

Comment: paste this layout in your question please , I meant to paste it as well in your question

Comment: What does it mean "my register button does not work" ?

Comment: that is the problem  bro  when I put toolbar my register button does not work.. but when I remove toolbar it again working properly

Comment: Sorry but "Button doesn't work" doesn't mean anything. Is it in the screen? Does the app crash? You can click it but nothing happens?

Comment: yes app will crash and i handle with try catch ..its give me this in catch. Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference error

Comment: but if i remove the toolbar the error will be gone

Comment: @MadScientist can you resolve this

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because your ScrollView's height is set to wrap_content, your parent Linear layout's height is set to match_parent and your toolbar Linear layout's height is set to be match_parent. You have to change your scrollview's height to be match_parent and your parent linear layout and toolbar linear layout heights to be wrap content. Something like this:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="false">

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:id="@+id/parent_linear_layout"
  tools:context=".ServicesAndRateList">

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

  <include
      android:id="@+id/toolbar1"
      layout="@layout/toolbar"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I would also suggest for yout to use constraint layout on your future layouts. Let me know if it works!